# Overlay 2 pictures (1 transparent) and download them overlayed

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, overlay

I have to program a website on which I should upload a picture and add a frame to it. I would save the frames as a transparent PNG and overlay them over the uploaded one. After that it should get downloaded with the overlayed frame.

Comment: It's technically impossible. You either have serve the final (combined) image or offer a separate download link for the combined version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Canvas element, and draw the two images in its context, later on you can get the data of the canvas and save it to a file.

Comment: Canvas is HTML5 so be aware that not every browser supports it.